# How to design the reward for an action which is the only legal action at some state

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am working on a RL project,but got stuck at one point: The task is continuous (Non-episodic). Following some suggestion from Sutton's [RL book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf), I am using a value function approximation method with average reward (differential return instead of discount return). For some state (represented by some features), only one action is legal. I am not sure how to design reward for such action. Is it ok to just assign the reward in the previous step? Could anyone tell me the best way to decide the reward for the only legal action. Thank you!

UPDATE:
To give more details, I added one simplified example:
Let me explain this by a simplified example: the state space consists of a job queue with fix size and a single server. The queue state is represented by the duration of jobs and the server state is represented by the time left to finish the current running job.  When the queue is not full and the server is idle, the agent can SCHEDULE a job to server for execution and see a state transition(taking next job into queue) or the agent can TAKE NEXT JOB into queue. But when the job queue is full and server is still running a job, the agent can do nothing except take a BLOCKING action and witness a state transit (time left to finish running job gets decreased by one unit time). The BLOCKING action is the only action that the agent can take in that state.

Comment: @DukeZhou Thanks, please see the update in question